# Putting image on a html page from API response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

I am very new to web development, ajax etc. I have access to Tenor api, so I can send a request like this:

```
https://api.tenor.com/v1/random?q=MYQUERYSTRING&key=MYAPIKEY&limit=1
```

It responds with an JSON document, which looks like this (I am pasting just the important stuff):

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "tags": [], 
      "url": "https://tenor.com/0liG.gif", 
      "media": [ some other JSON data down there ]
    }]
}
```

Now I need to access that `url` parameter. After a bit of googling I have found a partial solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <title>Sample Page</title>
      <script>
         var settings = {
           "async": true,
           "crossDomain": true,
           "url": "https://api.tenor.com/v1/random?q=MYQUERY&key=MYAPIKEY&limit=1",
           "method": "GET"
         }

         $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
           console.log(response);

           var content = response.results.url;
           $("#myUrl").append(content);
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Sample Page</h1>
      <div id="someid">URL: 
          <img id="myUrl" src="" />
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

But the image is not displayed.

I have opened the console, and I am absolutely sure that the response is full of data and contains the URL to the image I need.

How can I display this image?

Comment: What do you see when you do `console.inf(response)` ?

Comment: see [append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) and [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/). Append adds text to inner html

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `src` attribute of the image. Also, `results` is an array.

```
 $.ajax( settings ).done( function ( response ) {
       $( '#myUrl' ).attr( 'src', response.results[ 0 ].url );
 } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
 $("#myUrl").append(content);
```

with

```
 $("#myUrl").attr('src', content);
```

Comment: `results` is an array.

Comment: That's one thing, but `response.results.url` is still undefined. `response.results` is an array.

Comment: Of course, you´re right. Didn´t pay attention to this. Just saw the var "content".

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `src` attribute `img` tag as follows,

```
$.ajax( settings ).done( function ( response ) {

    if (response.results[0].length > 0) {
       var content = response.results[0].url; 
       $( '#myUrl' ).attr( 'src', content );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 mistakes on your code based on response object that you gave.

First:

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
           console.log(response);

           var content = response.results.url;
           $("#myUrl").append(content);
         });
```

the

`var content = response.results.url;`

should be

`var content = response.results[0].url;`

Second:

the `$("#myUrl").append(content);` should be   `$("#myUrl").attr('src', content);`

It Should Worrk after these 2 steps. but if it doesn't follow to

Third:

wrap everything inside $.ajax() with $(document).ready() like following code:

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(response);
    var content = response.results[0].url;
    $("#myUrl").attr('src', content);

    });
});
```

Hope thats solved your problem